# I can't change permissions in /media folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

On my laptop I have got installed Ubuntu 11.04 and VirtualBox with Ubuntu Server 12.10.
I have shared folder in /home/szymon/projekty_www. I can see content of this folder in virtual machine in /media/sf_projekty_www, but sadly I need root permision.

When I do:

```
root@ubuntu-server:/media# ls -l
```

I get answer:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 cze  7 08:54 cdrom
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 cze  7 14:38 sf_projekty_www
```

Of course I tried to change permissions:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /media/sf_projekty_www
```

but it does nothing. The permissions are the same:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 cze  7 08:54 cdrom
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 cze  7 14:38 sf_projekty_www
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is it mounted read/write, or read only?  Can you use sudo to get root permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That directory `sf_...` is mounted by VirtualBox with type *vboxsf* (ie all operations managed by vbox). You cannot change easily owner or access rights.

The recommend way to allow a user to access the directory is to make that user a member of the group *vboxsf*. To make *myuser* a member of that group:

```
$ sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a myuser
```

Restart the Virtual machine, then *myuser* should have access to the *sf* directory.

(See also comment below)

Comment: Actually, you don't need to restart - just log that user out and back in again, possibly even on a per-shell (window) basis.